# Binding the labels property for custom livechart in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I'm creating a custom LiveChart control by creating a dependency property for the SeriesCollection, Axis labels, the titles for the x and y axes. When using the control in my main project, the binding is working for all properties except for the Axis labels (xLables). Below is the code for the liveChart custom control. Your help is appreciated.

XAML code

```
UserControl x:Class="SalesDashboard.Controls.LiveChartUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SalesDashboard.Controls"
             xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:LiveChartUserControl}}}">
        
        <lvc:CartesianChart  Series="{Binding cSeries}"  LegendLocation="Bottom">
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis Title="{Binding xTitle}" Labels="{Binding xLabels}"  FontSize="15">
                    <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                        <lvc:Separator Stroke="Transparent"/>
                    </lvc:Axis.Separator>

                </lvc:Axis>

            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>

            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:Axis Title="{Binding yTitle}" LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}" FontSize="15">
                    <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                        <lvc:Separator Stroke="Transparent"/>
                    </lvc:Axis.Separator>
                </lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>

        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;

namespace SalesDashboard.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for LiveChartUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LiveChartUserControl : UserControl
    {

        public Func<double, string> Formatter { get; set; }

        public SeriesCollection cSeries
        {
            get { return (SeriesCollection)GetValue(SeriesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SeriesProperty, value); }
        }

        public string[] xLables
        {
            get { return (string[])GetValue(xLabelsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(xLabelsProperty, value); }
        }
       
        public string xTitle
        {
            get { return GetValue(xTitleProperty).ToString(); }
            set { SetValue(xTitleProperty, value); }
        }
       
        public string yTitle
        {
            get { return GetValue(yTitleProperty).ToString(); }
            set { SetValue(yTitleProperty, value ); }
        }

           public static readonly DependencyProperty SeriesProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(cSeries), typeof(SeriesCollection), typeof(LiveChartUserControl));
       
            public static readonly DependencyProperty xLabelsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("xLables", typeof(string[]), typeof(LiveChartUserControl), 
            new PropertyMetadata
            (null));

            public static readonly DependencyProperty xTitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(xTitle), typeof(string), typeof(LiveChartUserControl));

            public static readonly DependencyProperty yTitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(yTitle), typeof(string), typeof(LiveChartUserControl));


        public LiveChartUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Formatter = value => value.ToString("N"); 

        }
    }
}
```

The implementation

```
 <controls:LiveChartUserControl x:Name="Livchart1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" cSeries="{Binding SeriesCollection}" xLables="{Binding Labels}"  xTitle="{Binding xAxixTitle}" yTitle="{Binding yAxixTitle}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the typo. You have registered dependency property as `xLables` but in the binding you are using `xLabels`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty xLabelsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("xLables", typeof(string[]), typeof(LiveChartUserControl), 
        new PropertyMetadata
        (null));

Labels="{Binding xLabels}"
```

Renaming `xLables` to `xLabels` should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you dear, yes it is working perfectly now. Thanks again.

Comment: @AliAlfaraj Great. You can mark the answer as useful if it resolves the issue.